# Simple expense tracker

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have posted below a small project of mine in AS3 regarding a super simple Expense Tracker. I finally made it basically functional, and I learnt A LOT in the way. But even I can tell that my design is horrible. If anyone was kind enough as to mention my mistakes to me and/or give me some advice, I would be extremely thankful!

This is basically my main design:

- `DocumentClass` calls `mainScreen` and `balanceField`.
- `MainScreen` calls `mainButton`.
- `MainButton` dispatches `Event` to `mainScreen` when clicked to make `mainScreen` invisible.
- I repeat the same process with `secondaryScreen` and `secondaryButton` (using the same event as trigger).
- After I click on `secondaryButton`, `InputScreen` is called.
- `InputScreen` handles the `balanceField` from within, using `static var`s from `DocumentClass`.
- `okButton` in `inputScreen` dispatches `Event`, same as before to make this invisible and the `mainScreen` visible again.

Here are some pieces of my code:

`DocumentClass`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
    {
        public static var mainScreen:MainScreen;
        public static var balanceField:Balance;
        public static var actual:Number = 0;

        public function DocumentClass() 
        {

            mainScreen = new MainScreen();
            mainScreen.x = 0;
            mainScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(mainScreen);

            balanceField = new Balance();
            balanceField.x = 50;
            balanceField.y = 0;
            addChild(balanceField);            
        }            
    }        
}
```

This is my main class. Following are 2 subsequent classes:

`MainScreen`:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MainScreen extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var expenseButton:MainButton;
        public var incomeButton:MainButton;

        public function MainScreen() 
        {
            expenseButton = new MainButton('Expense');
            expenseButton.x = 200;
            expenseButton.y = 200;
            addChild(expenseButton);
            expenseButton.addEventListener( ButtonEvent.DEAD, onButtonClick);

            incomeButton = new MainButton('Income');
            incomeButton.x = 200;
            incomeButton.y = 400;
            addChild(incomeButton);
            incomeButton.addEventListener( ButtonEvent.DEAD, onButtonClick);

        }

        public function onButtonClick (buttonEvent:ButtonEvent ):void
        {
            this.visible = false;
        }    
    }        
}
```

I am gonna skip some stuff like the button functions:

`MainButton`:

```
package  
{

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MainButton extends MovieClip
    {
        public var nextScreen:SecondaryScreen;
        public var category:String;

        public function MainButton(categ:String) 
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOverHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOutHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPressHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseHandler);

            buttonText.text = (categ);

            this.buttonMode = true;
            this.mouseChildren = false; 
            this.useHandCursor = true;
            category=categ;                
        }

        function onReleaseHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            if (category == 'Expense')
            {
                nextScreen=new SecondaryScreen(category);

            }

            if (category == 'Income')
            {
                nextScreen=new SecondaryScreen(category);

            }
            nextScreen.x = 0;
            nextScreen.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(nextScreen);
            dispatchEvent( new ButtonEvent(ButtonEvent.DEAD));
        }                
    }        
}
```

And the `InputScreen`:

```
package  
{    
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.*;
    import DocumentClass;

    public class InputScreen extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var okButton:OkButton;
        public var wvalue:String;
        public var gvalue:Number;
        public var category:String;
        public var total:Number = 0;

        public function InputScreen(categ:String,type:String) 
        {    
            inputField.border = true;

            okButton = new OkButton("Ok");
            okButton.x = 200;
            okButton.y = 350;
            addChild(okButton);
            okButton.addEventListener( ButtonEvent.DEAD, onButtonClick);

            categField.text = (categ);
            typeField.text = ("Type: " + type);

            category = categ;        
        }

        public function onButtonClick (buttonEvent:ButtonEvent ):void
        {
            wvalue = inputField.text;
            gvalue = Number(wvalue);

            if (category == "Expense")
            {
                gvalue = -1*gvalue;
            }

            total = total + gvalue;

            DocumentClass.actual += total;
            DocumentClass.balanceField.balanceText.text = ("Wallet: " + DocumentClass.actual + "€");
            DocumentClass.mainScreen.visible = true;
        }    
    }    
}
```

Finally, my `Event` and `balanceField`:

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class ButtonEvent extends Event 
    {
        public static const DEAD:String = "dead";

        public function ButtonEvent( type:String )
        {
            super( type );
        }
    }
}



package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;


    public class Balance extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var balance:Number = 0;

        public function Balance() 
        {
            balanceText.text = ("Wallet: " + balance + "€");
        }
    }
}
```

[In case anyone needs the rest of the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tpualcvh6t2dtf/Expense%20Tracker%20V1.rar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said your structure is horrible, but it's not really *horrible*! I suggest you skim [this](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-flash/T-The-Model-View-Controller-Design-Pattern-in-Actionscript-3/ID-144/) (a bit old, but relevant) and try to read up on coding patterns (especially AS3 related) so you have a wider knowledge of what is possible.

So, these lines are unused:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOverHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOutHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPressHandler);
```

Unless you plan on having features for each of these states, you can take them out. Right after that, you have:

```
buttonText.text = (categ);
```

The parentheses around `categ` aren't necessary. And I'm not sure where `buttonText` is created, but it looks like it just appears! In the handler below that, the argument `myEvent` isn't very concise. It's a simple name, which could be more specific, or less possessive (`e`, `evt`, `handlingEvent`, etc.).

Directly below that, you have:

```
if (category == 'Expense') {
    nextScreen=new SecondaryScreen(category);
}
if (category == 'Income') {
    nextScreen=new SecondaryScreen(category);
}
```

This could either be turned into a `switch(category)` if you have plans on changing the action a category makes. However, neither of these categories requires special treatment in these `if`s, so why not just take out the conditionals completely! Leave it as a one line assignment.

In the class of `InputScreen`, a variable `wvalue` is created and used in this context:

```
wvalue = inputField.text;
gvalue = Number(wvalue);
```

Consider removing the extra variable and simplifying it to:

```
gvalue = Number(inputField.text);
```

To be consistent, I suggest separating `ButtonEvent` and `Balance` into two files. Especially if you decide to add controlling code in the `Balance` class.

### Naming

I touched on this earlier, but it's come back! The names you've chosen for a few things are very misleading and confusing.

First off, `DocumentClass` really doesn't need `Class` appended on the end. We know it's going to be a class. However, Document is a bit broad, try finding a name that fits the situation better.

Is `public static var balanceField:Balance;` an account balance or a field? I think you should change one of those names (variable or class). The Balance class is a bit misleading. I want to believe that a balance class should be handing the business of the deposits and withdraws. Perhaps a better name for that class would be BalanceButton?

In `MainButton(categ:String)`, `categ` could really just be `category`. It doesn't hurt.

In `InputScreen`, the variable `gvalue` is used. I can't even tell what it stands for! What is the "g"? Same class, the global `total` is made, but only used in the one function. Unless it's used outside of it, perhaps reduce it's scope as to not pollute your global scope. In fact, reassess the variables that are currently global, and see if they actually do need to be global.

Lastly, I'm not sure what `ButtonEvent`'s `DEAD` means. Usually events have verbs as constants to use.

Comment: 1)I just didn't copy the event functions for more space.  

2)Thank you for all the advice! I will fix all that you have mentioned!  

3)Any advice on the basic structure? Like changing parent-child relationships, or the static vars in DocumentClass?

Comment: Regarding `statics`, read [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f31.html). You actually don't need them to be static! Try to find some similarities between your different screen classes and your different button classes. You may be able to create a parent class for screens and buttons, and then extend those into `InputScreen`s and `OkButton`s!